# golang sort slice ascending or descending

Tags: sorting, go

I need to sort a slice of a type that is coming from a 3rd party package. Based on some condition the order must be ascending or descending.

The solution I come up with is:

```
type fooAscending []foo

func (v fooAscending) Len() int           { return len(v) }
func (v fooAscending) Swap(i, j int)      { v[i], v[j] = v[j], v[i] }
func (v fooAscending) Less(i, j int) bool { return v[i].Amount < v[j].Amount }

type fooDescending []foo

func (v fooDescending) Len() int           { return len(v) }
func (v fooDescending) Swap(i, j int)      { v[i], v[j] = v[j], v[i] }
func (v fooDescending) Less(i, j int) bool { return v[i].Amount > v[j].Amount }

if someCondition {
    sort.Sort(fooAscending(array))
} else {
    sort.Sort(fooDescending(array))
}
```

Is there a better way to do this. 13 lines of code for this task and most of it is duplicated, seems a bit too much.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

As of Go 1.8, there is an easier way to sort a slice that does not require you to define new types. You simply pass an anonymous function to the `sort.Slice` function.

```
a := []int{5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i] < a[j]
})
for _, v := range a {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

This will sort in ascending order, if you want the opposite, simply write `a[i] > a[j]` in the anonymous function.

Comment: Sadly it's restricted on int type

Comment: @LewisChan it is not restricted on int types; the int parameters are indexes to the slice, which can be a slice of strings.

Answer (score 30):

You're looking for [`sort.Reverse`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_Reverse). That will let you say:

```
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(fooAscending(s)))
```

Answer (score 24):

My answer below is based on the assumption that the slice that you are receiving from a third party package is of a basic Go type.

To sort slices of basic types, use the sort package utilities. Here is an example that sorts a slice of string and a slice of int.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    sl := []string{"mumbai", "london", "tokyo", "seattle"}
    sort.Sort(sort.StringSlice(sl))
    fmt.Println(sl)

    intSlice := []int{3,5,6,4,2,293,-34}
    sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(intSlice))
    fmt.Println(intSlice)
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
[london mumbai seattle tokyo]
[-34 2 3 4 5 6 293]
```

Go to [Go Playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/_b8RCL3NpI) to try it out yourself.

A few things of note:

1. Sorting basic Go types does not require implementing functions such as Len() that belong to sort.Interface. You need to take that route only for composite types.
2. Just wrap the type of a basic type using an appropriate Interface method provider, e.g. [StringSlice](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#StringSlice), [IntSlice](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#IntSlice), or [Float64Slice](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Float64Slice), and sort.
3. The slice is sorted in-place, and hence does not return a copy of the sorted slice.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is good, but I disagree with their suggestion on descending:

```
a[i] > a[j]
```

With `sort.Slice`, the provided function is supposed to represent an
implementation of "less than":

> `func Slice(x interface{}, less func(i, j int) bool)`
>
> `Slice` sorts the slice `x` given the provided `less` function. It panics if `x` is not a slice.

So writing a "greater than" function, isn't really true to the given description. Better would be to reverse the indexes:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sort"
)

func main() {
   a := []int{5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
   sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool {
      return a[j] < a[i]
   })
   fmt.Println(a) // [9 8 7 5 4 3]
}
```

both should return the same result, but I think one is more idiomatic.

https://golang.org/pkg/sort#Slice

Comment: Thanks for submitting this answer, it helped me understand how to conceptualize the function and what to return.

Answer (score 8):

In Go 1.21, a new package, [slices](https://pkg.go.dev/slices), has been added. It contains several generic functions to work with slices.

`slices.Sort()` [[ref]](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Sort) can sort a slice of any [ordered type](https://pkg.go.dev/cmp#Ordered) like `int`, `float64`, `string`. It is faster than `sort.Sort()`.

```
s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}

// sorts in asc order
slices.Sort(s)

// reverse the slice for desc order
slices.Reverse(s)
```

If the elements of your slice do not have an ordered type, then you can use `slices.SortFunc()`. The following example has been taken from the [official docs](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#SortFunc).

```
package main

import (
    "cmp"
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func CmpPerson(a, b Person) int {
    if a.Name == b.Name {
        return cmp.Compare(a.Age, b.Age)
    }
    return cmp.Compare(a.Name, b.Name)
}

func main() {
    people := []Person{
        {"Gopher", 13},
        {"Alice", 55},
        {"Bob", 24},
        {"Alice", 20},
    }

    slices.SortFunc(people, CmpPerson)

    // Output: [{Alice 20} {Alice 55} {Bob 24} {Gopher 13}]
    fmt.Println(people)
}
```

Unlike `sort.Slice()`, the comparator function `CmpPerson()` has elements of the slice, not their indices, as parameters.

So now, you can either use the same comparator with `slices.Reverse()` or you can define another comparator for descending order.

Note that `slices.SortFunc()` is not [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). For stable sorting, you can use `slices.SortStableFunc()`, which has the same signature as `slices.SortFunc()`.

Answer (score 6):

maybe you could use `sort.Sort` method to sort slice. :)

```golang
func TestSorted(t *testing.T) {
    nums := []int{4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1}
    // descending
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(nums)))
    fmt.Println(nums) // [5 4 3 3 2 2 1]
    // ascending
    sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(nums))
    fmt.Println(nums) // [1 2 2 3 3 4 5]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can import the "sort" package from standard library of golang . then you can use either "Slice" or "SliceStable" function to sort your slice. it is recommended to use the second one like this :

```
sort.SliceStable(yourSlice , anonnymousFunction)
```

example :
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)
func main() {
    a := []int{4,5,9,6,8,3,5,7,99,58,1}
    sort.SliceStable(a, func(i,j int )bool{
        //i,j are represented for two value of the slice .
        return a[i] < a[j]
    })
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = []string{"b", "a", "e", "c", "d"}
sort.Strings(names)
fmt.Println("Sorted in alphabetical order", names)
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.StringSlice(names)))
fmt.Println("Sorted in reverse order", names)
```

link for The Go Playgound https://play.golang.org/p/Q8KY_JE__kx

Answer (score 0):

##### Sort in ascending order:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    // unsorted string and integer slices
    strData := []string{"Go", "Bravo", "Gopher", "Alpha", "Grin", "Delta"}
    intData := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}

    // sort in-place in ascending order
    sort.Ints(intData)
    sort.Strings(strData)

    // print
    fmt.Println(intData)
    fmt.Println(strData)
}
```

Output:

```
[Alpha Bravo Delta Go Gopher Grin]
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

##### Sort in descending order:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    // unsorted int and string slices
    strData := []string{"Go", "Bravo", "Gopher", "Alpha", "Grin", "Delta"}
    intData := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4}

    // sort in-place in descending order
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(intData)))
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.StringSlice(strData)))

    // print
    fmt.Println(intData)
    fmt.Println(strData)
}
```

Output:

```
[6 5 4 3 2 1]
[Grin Gopher Go Delta Bravo Alpha]
```

Answer (score -2):

if for any reasons you can't or don't want to use the sort package, the following will implement a bubble sort type of sorting (it accepts an int64 slice and returns an int64 slice):

```
func sortSlice ( S []int64 ) []int64 {
  // sort using bubblesort, comparing each pairs of numbers and ensuring that left is lower than right
  for i := len(S); i > 0 ; i-- {
    for j := 1; j < i; j++ {
      if S[j-1] > S[j] {
        // swap
        intermediate := S[j]
        S[j] = S[j-1]
        S[j-1] = intermediate
      }
    }
  }
  return S
}
```

Comment: Please don't use bubble sort on production environments because it has very poor performance. For testing purposes it may be ok.